# why my.function$ does not open my returned values to select in R

Tags: r, function, matrix, error-handling, return

I wrote function below. my function name is M.step(). I returned multiple parameters including variable, vector, lists as a whole list.
now I want to run my function and by M.step$tau.vec get its calculated tau.vec.
but when I type that, I get error :Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable.

how can I fix this?

```
    M.step<- function( pi.df.new, S,A2, A1, I, tau.vec, rho.vec, sig.sq.vec,
                   Y.list, Sigma.list, Psi.list, ll.old ){
  
  k <- ncol(pi.df.new)-1
  p <- dim(Y.list[[1]])[1]
  Tt<- dim(Y.list[[1]])[2]
  
  tau.vec <- vector()
  for (i in 1:k) {
    tau.vec[i] <- colSums(pi.df.new[i])/nrow(pi.df.new)
  }
  
  
  
 
  for (i in seq(nrho)){
    low <- unlist(mapply(seq, 1, (Tt - 1):1))
    up <- unlist(mapply(seq, 1:(Tt - 1), 1))
    lower <- rho.vec[i]^low
    upper <- rho.vec[i]^up
    Psi.mat[, , i][lower.tri(Psi.mat[, , i])] <- lower
    Psi.mat[, , i][upper.tri(Psi.mat[, , i])] <- upper
    Psi.list[[i]] <- ((1-rho.vec[i]^2)^(1/Tt-1))*Psi.mat[,,i]
    Psi.inv.list[[i]] <- solve(Psi.list[[i]])
    Psi.det.vec[i] <- det(Psi.list[[i]])
  }
  
  
  
  Phi.mat.new <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(pi.df.new), ncol = k, byrow = TRUE)
  for(j in 1:nrow(pi.df.new)){
    for(i in 1:k){
      Phi.mat.new[j,i] <- mGpdf(Y.list[[j]], S, beta.list[[i]], Sigma.inv.list[[i]], Psi.inv.list[[i]], Sigma.det.vec[i], Psi.det.vec[i])
    }
  }
  
  
  
  return(list(tau.vec= tau.vec, rho.vec = rho.vec, sig.sq.vec= sig.sq.vec,
              Sigma.list = Sigma.list , Psi.list = Psi.list , ll= ll ))
  
  }
```

Comment: You would need to call `M.step` with the relevant arguments and save the results to an object: `my.M <- M.step(pi.df.new, S,A2, A1, I, tau.vec, rho.vec, sig.sq.vec, Y.list, Sigma.list, Psi.list, ll.old )`.  Then, you could find the returned result with `my.M$tau.vec`.

Comment: Your variable `M.step` is a function and it will return a list with a named element `tau.vec`. You need to actually call your function before it can return a value. You need to call your function with something like `M.step(pi.df.new=10, S=4,A2=6, A1=6,...)` (with values for all your parameters, I have no idea what actual reasonable values are in your case). Then you can extract at the end `M.step(pi.df.new=, S=,A2=, A1=,...)$tau.vec`